# How can I zip 4 arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, zip

zip(a, zip(b, c)).map { ($0, $1.0, $1.1) }
Here three are being done but I need to zip four arrays.

Comment: `zip(zip(a, b), zip(c, d)).map { ($0.0, $0.1, $1.0, $1.1) }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the prettiest, but it works:

```
zip(a, zip(b, zip(c, d))).map { ($0, $1.0, $1.1.0, $1.1.1) }
```